# javascript .appendChild(newNode); not working with <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am facing JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference for following function.

```
    insertBefore: function(newNode, beforeNode) {
        beforeNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, beforeNode);
    },

    insertAfter: function(newNode, afterNode) {
        var next = afterNode.nextSibling;
        if (next) {
            afterNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, next);
        }
        else {
            afterNode.parentNode.appendChild(newNode);
        }
    },
```

It was/is working find with ie7 but, I am suppose to work with ie9 renderer

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />.
```

Found that after changing meta `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />` To `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` it through run time error.

Any idea to fix this???

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where `insertAfter()` is invoked? It seems that `afterNode.parentNode` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan..

it's in C++ file it's a combination on java script ind c++.
But it's working fine with ie7 meta, Do you steel think that there is some issue to invoke it?

Comment: From what I can see the problem is only Javascript related. I assume Javascript can't find `afterNode` or `afterNode.parentNode`, that means that that variable is not correctly passed to the **insertAfter** function.

Comment: Variable passed correctly and It's working fine with 
<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=7” />

It seems .appendChild is not working with 
<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=9” />

let me update it in my question.

Comment: Also update the question with the runtime error, which is the key to me. I don't know what the C++ parts does but on the IE9 it seems that javascript is not able to find the `<head>` where to append the `<meta>`.
Also try `afterNode.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />');` but I think the error will be the same.

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unhandled exception at line 163, column 17 in misp://mscjsres.dll::MCDOM.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference